# Calculating determinant Dn

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, determinant

Do i have to calculate this determinant ***Dn*** with **recurrence formulas** because i have difficulties with first and last row having 1 and 2, so i can't have Dn-1!

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
5 & 8 & 3 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 8 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & . & . & .\\
0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 8 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 5 & 8 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & 2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_n$ be the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix with 5s, 8s and 3s along the three central diagonals. Multiplying out this determinant using the first and last rows gives $$E_{n+2}=8E_{n+1}-15E_n$$ and we obtain the formula $$E_n=\frac {1}{2} (5^{n+1}-3^{n+1}).$$

Let $D_n$ be the determinant of the given matrix, where $n\ge 3$. Multiplying out this determinant using the first and last rows gives
$$E_{n-2}-16E_{n-3}+60E_{n-4}=\frac {1}{2} (5^{n-2}-7\times 3^{n-2}).$$

Comment: But if we do the proof, 1/2(5^n-2 - 7*3^n-2)  does not give us the correct solution, example for n=3.

Comment: I get -8, what do you get?

Comment: If we use formula yes it is -8, but if we calculate determinant 3x3 the result is -31.

Comment: I've given the working above.

Answer (score 0):

**Result to answer query**

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0\\ 
5 & 8 & 3 \\
 0 & 2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
has determinant $1\times (8\times 1-3 \times 2)-2\times (5\times 1-3 \times 0)=-8.$

Comment: Do we have the third row 0  5  8  at the  Dn determinant

Comment: I think the natural meaning of the dots is that the top and bottom rows are 1 2 0 and 0 2 1. With all other rows 5 8 3.

Comment: I think this determinant have just the first row 1 2 0 ... 0 0 0, and last row 0 0 0 ... 0 2 1 and the other part have 5 8 3 along the three central diagonals.

Comment: So do I. Just as in the matrix for $n=3$ shown above.

Comment: But i thought we have to take the 3 first rows and 3 first columns of the Dn determinant above

Comment: Even if you think that, the formula that I have given applies to $D_n$ as you have drawn it.

Comment: Thank you for all these explanations.I am understanding now :) .

Comment: Glad to be of help.